# How many tables per MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, database

On godaddy it says I get 25 databases. Does that mean that I only get 25 tables or can I have multiple tables in a database? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can have multiple tables per database.

Comment: A table is not a database. So many many tables. 25 databases.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL has no limit on the number of databases. The underlying file system may have a limit on the number of directories.

Ref: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/database-count-limit.html

More info: https://www.quora.com/Is-there-a-maximum-number-of-tables-a-MySQL-database-can-have?share=1

Answer (score -1):

You can have 25 databases and multiple tables in each database

Answer (score -1):

You can use `show databases;` to see how many databases you can access to;

Then `use name-of-db` enter the `database`, then `show tables`, to see how many tables in this database.